# Python3/Tornado/HTML file upload modifies file

Tags: html, python-3.x, tornado

I am trying to upload a file through an HTML page. This file should be written to a new file. Python manages the Post.

My post method is as follows:

```
async def post(self, id):
    """
    Used to send a component to a node OTA
    :return:
    """
    # write to file
    path = "files/"
    fileinfo = self.request.files['filearg'][0]

    fname = fileinfo['filename']
    extn = os.path.splitext(fname)[1]
    cname = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extn
    fh = open(path + cname, 'w')
    fh.write(str(fileinfo['body']))
    fh.close()
    ...
```

However, this modifies the file!
If I give a .java file to the upload form, e.g.,

public class Test_SensorReading extends UJCmp{

```
public static int CMP_ID = 111; //UJCmpTypes.TEST_SENSORREADING;
public static int NB_INSTR_TO_RUN = 10000;
public static int ALLOC_MEM = 10;

public static int wait_s = 10;

public static void main(){
    Test_SensorReading inst = new Test_SensorReading();
    inst.execute();
}
...
```

The result in the new file is.

```
b'public class Test_SensorReading extends UJCmp{\n\t\n\tpublic static int CMP_ID = 111; //UJCmpTypes.TEST_SENSORREADING;\n\tpublic static int NB_INSTR_TO_RUN = 10000;\n\tpublic static int ALLOC_MEM = 10;\n\t\n\tpublic static int wait_s = 10;\n\n\tpublic static void main(){\n\t\tTest_SensorReading inst = new Test_SensorReading();\n\t\tinst.execute();\n\t}...
```

And the rest of the method fails.
I suspect it is an issue that the the file is modified somewhere, but have not been able to determine where. Basically, the new file should be the exact same as the old file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: I should've specified the encoding, utf-8, in the str() command.
Like so:

```
str(fileinfo['body'],'utf-8')
```

This produces the same file!